# Indexable quine

Tags: code-golf, quine

The goal of this challenge is to make a program that outputs the nth letter of its source code where n is given as input to the program. Like most quine challenges, you are not allowed to read your source code as a file or use any builtin quine functions.

### Input

An integer 0 <= n < len(program).

### Output

The nth character (not byte) of your program.

### Winning

Like most codegolf questions, you win the challenge by using the lowest number of bytes to solve the challenge.

### Bonuses

-5% If your program supports negative indices python style (e.g. -1 would be the last character of your program). If used with the below bonus, your ranges must support negative indices.
-20% If your program supports ranges as input (any format) in addition to the above requirements.
-25% If your program complete both bonuses.

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=70727,OVERRIDE_USER=32700;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?([\d\.]+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Are quine builtins forbidden?

Comment: @Mego yes, they are.

Comment: Do bonuses stack (100% - 20% - 5% = 75%) or multiply (100% * 80% * 95% = 76%)?

Comment: Do programs that don't actually read their input count?

Comment: @ETHproductions Stack.

Comment: @Neil Yes, it is already too late in my opinion to change that.

Comment: Is `Piet` throwing an error applicable?

Comment: Do you have to support mixed positive and negative ranges, e.g. `0..-1` (entire program), `-1..0` (last character followed by first character)?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot If you want to go for both bonuses, you do have to support mixed positive and negative ranges. How you interpret that is up to you.

Comment: For the 20% bonus, must we be able to accept _both_ integers and arrays as input, or _only_ arrays?

Comment: @Shaggy both integers and ranges.

Answer (score 13):

## Pyth, 0.75 bytes

(Also happens to be a CJam polyglot, and probably many other languages.)

```
0
```

Expects input on STDIN:

```
llama@llama:~$ echo 0..0 | pyth -c '0'
0
```

Any single digit works, of course. Not exactly the most interesting challenge in Pyth.

Comment: It happens to be a polyglot in many other languages, too.

Comment: works in PlatyPar too

Comment: and Japt, and Jolf, and almost every language with implicit output

Comment: And PHP, which is clearly the best language for golfing.

Answer (score 8):

## Javascript ES6, 31 bytes

```
$=_=>`$=${$};$()`[prompt()];$()
```

## Explanation

The standard quine framework:

```
$=_=>`$=${$};$()`;$()
```

`[prompt()]`, which is the addon, gets the value at the input index of the resulting quine string.

Answer (score 6):

## , 9 chars / 19 bytes

```
⟮ɕṡ+ᶈ0)⎖ï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=3&code=%E2%9F%AE%C9%95%E1%B9%A1%2B%E1%B6%880%29%E2%8E%96%C3%AF)</kbd>

*Ay, 19th byte!*

`0` works too (and is much better), but it's way too trivial for my liking.

In addition, `ℹ ï,⧺ï` would also work, but quine functions aren't allowed.

### Explanation

The standard quine framework is `⟮ɕṡ+ᶈ0`.

`)⎖ï` takes the resulting quine string and gets the character at the input index.

---

## Bonus solution, 11.4 chars / 25.65 bytes

```
⟮ᵖ…ɕṡ+ᶈ0;ôᵍï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=-2&code=%E2%9F%AE%E1%B5%96%E2%80%A6%C9%95%E1%B9%A1%2B%E1%B6%880%3B%C3%B4%E1%B5%8D%C3%AF)</kbd>

This one qualifies for the 5% bonus, but still does not beat my original submission.

### Explanation

This one uses the stack. `ᵖ…ɕṡ+ᶈ0;` just pushes the quine string's individual characters to the stack, and `ôᵍï` directly outputs the character at the input index (positive or negative) in the stack.

Comment: Why haven't you made an encoding for this yet?

Comment: Updates are coming too fast! Can't keep up!

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 12.35 bytes

```
{s"_~"+ri=}_~
```

The program is **13 bytes** long and qualifies for the **× 0.95** bonus. [Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=e3MiX34iK3JpPX1ffg&input=LTI)

#### How it works

```
{         }      Define a code block.
           _~    Push a copy and execute the copy.
 s               Cast the original code block to string.
  "_~"+          Append "_~".
       ri        Read an integer from STDIN.
         =       Retrieve the character at that index.
```

Comment: Of course, `0` would have been slightly shorter...

Answer (score 5):

## Polyglot, 0 bytes

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run) (you'll have to select a language yourself)

The challenge specifies taking an integer \$ 0 \le n \lt \text{len}(\text{program}) \$, but with a 0-byte program there is no integer that is both ≥ 0 and < 0. This means the program can do whatever it wants.

When I say polyglot, I mean that it works in any language whatsoever.

Comment: This feels like abuse of a loophole to me.

Comment: Empty quine is improper

Comment: It isn't a program that outputs itself by virtue of being empty and doing nothing, it's a program that never has to output anything :P

Comment: `When I say polyglot, I mean that it works in any language whatsoever.` There are in fact many programming languages that consider an empty source code file as a syntax error.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt It doesn't matter. The program can output whatever it wants, because there are no requirements on what it has to output.

Comment: The problem is, you claim this is was e. g. a proper program in Pascal, but it is syntactically not. @Shaggy The loophole is [non-trivial output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8246/94076).

Comment: Yeah, I would consider this a loophole through triviality. It _is_ funny though, since it is _technically_ correct.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 53 * 0.75 = 39.75

```
$><<(<<2*2+?2)[eval gets]
$><<(<<2*2+?2)[eval gets]
2
```

Generates a HEREDOC string delimited by a `2` on its own line, concatenates it (`*2`) and then adds in the final `2` via a character literal. Slices into it using Ruby's built in `String#[]`, which supports positive integers, negative integers, and ranges (input in the form `m..n`). `$><<` is output. (`puts` would require an extra space here).

Comment: I think `gets.to_i` would do the same thing as `eval gets`, and be clearer. It wouldn't handle non-integer input, but that's not necessary anyway

Comment: That's normally what I'd do, but this gets the bonus for handling Ranges. (Also the non-existent bonus for being turing complete).

Comment: Ah, I missed that. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 38.25 bytes

```
a="a=%p;$><<(a%%a)[eval gets]";$><<(a%a)[eval gets]
```

Support negative indices and ranges. I blatantly picked up both `$><<` and the `eval` trick from histocrat, and the quine trick was someone else's to begin with, so I'll make this CW.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

All of the following use 0-based, modular indexing and support negative indexing.

```
gg
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Z2c&input=MgotbVA)

```
gg     :Implicit input of integer
g      :Index into
 g     :Literal "g"
```

### Original, 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Based on [one of ETH's standard Japt quines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156362/58974).

```
gBîQi"gBîQi
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Z0LuUWkiZ0LuUWk&input=MTEKLW1Q) (Includes full test suite)

```
gBîQi"gBîQi     :Implicit input of integer
g               :Index into
 B              :  11
  î             :  Repeat to length B
   Q            :    Quotation mark
    i           :    Prepend
     "gBîQi     :      String literal
```

#### Array input, 13 bytes

Same as above with the `m` at the start being `map` and the `D` being `13`, in place of `11`.

```
mgDîQi"mgDîQi
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bWdE7lFpIm1nRO5RaQ&input=WzAgMSAyIDMgNCA1IDYgNyA4IDkgMTAgMTEgLTFdCi1Q)

Comment: You can multiply by \$ 0.95 \$ if you support negative inputs

Comment: I don't like bonuses, @TheThonnu; I don't think they should be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 6 bytes

```
«•.\ü
```

Includes a trailing space.

### Explaination

```
«•.\ü 
«      # Push the remainer of the code as a function and continue execution
 •.    # Append a space to the end of the function as a string
   \   # Swap the string under the input value
    ü  # Get the character at that index
       # A trailing space is included to ensure quine validity.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///Q6kcNi/RiDu9R@P//vwEA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 46.55 bytes

```
a="a=%r;print(a%%a)[input()]";print(a%a)[input()]
```

Supports negative indices.

Comment: Yes, this supports negative indicies.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 122 bytes

```
main=getLine>>= \i->putChar$(!!(read i))$p++show p where p="main=getLine>>= \\i->putChar$(!!(read i))$p++show p where p="
```

Ungolfed:

```
main=getLine>>= \i->putChar$(!!(read i))$p++show p
 where p="main=getLine>>= \\i->putChar$(!!(read i))$p++show p\n where p="
```

Answer (score 1):

### Befunge 93, 5 bytes

This is pretty (very) late but I'll post it anyway:

```
&0g,@
```

Comment: This is on the edge of being legal IMO. It doesn't read its own source code *as a file*, but it does read its own source code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 32 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 26.34 * 0.75 \$ \approx \$ 19.75 bytes

```
"D34CXx+xs+s+sAI"D34CXx+xs+s+sAI
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhY3FZRcjE2cIyq0K4q1gdDRE50PUQdVvmBPtIGOgqmOgiGQMgTSuiAM4ugamsZC1AAA)

Based on [*@lyxal*'s Thunno quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256337/114446). Supports negative indices and ranges.